# How would I switch from an Array to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, arraylist

I have all the data saving to an array right now. How would I switch it to saving in a ArrayList of objects instead? I have a basic student object class written but need help switching it over to saving in an Arraylist. All help is greatly appreciated. The arraylist is created on line 28 and the data is set at line 300. The question is how to modify code to store in an ArrayList instead

```
public class IAdvise extends JFrame {

   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
   String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Name", "Major", "GPA", "Campus", "Home Address", "Phone Number", "Email", "Current CST courses", "Past CST course", "Fusture CST courses", "Notes"};
   Object[][] data = new Object[60][12];
   ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();

   JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
        @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
         return false;
      }
   };
   JFrame frame, frame1;
   JPanel buttonPanel, buttonPanel2, tablePanel, addPanel, editPanel;
   JLabel labelID, labelName, labelMajor, labelGPA, labelCampus, labelAddress, labelPhone, labelEmail,labelCurrent, labelPast, labelFuture, labelNotes;
   JTextField txtID, txtName, txtMajor, txtGPA, txtCampus, txtAddress, txtPhone, txtEmail, txtCurrent, txtPast, txtFuture, txtNotes;
   JButton btnAdd, btnEdit, btnDelete, btnSort, btnSave, btnAddInput, btnCancel;
   int keyCode, rowIndex, rowNumber, noOfStudents;
   IAdvise.ButtonHandler bh = new IAdvise.ButtonHandler();


   public IAdvise() {
      table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new IAdvise.RowListener());
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(50);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(250);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setPreferredWidth(150);
      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setPreferredWidth(150);

      table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
      table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      btnAdd = new JButton("Add Student");
      btnAdd.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit = new JButton("EDIT");
      btnEdit.addActionListener(bh);
      btnEdit.setEnabled(false); 
      btnDelete = new JButton("DELETE");
      btnDelete.addActionListener(bh);
      btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
      btnSort = new JButton("Update");
      btnSort.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
      btnSave.addActionListener(bh);
      btnSave.setActionCommand("Save");


      btnAddInput = new JButton("Add Student");
      btnAddInput.addActionListener(bh);
      btnAddInput.setActionCommand("AddInput");
      btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
      btnCancel.addActionListener(bh);

      labelID = new JLabel("ID");
      labelName = new JLabel("NAME");
      labelMajor = new JLabel("Major");
      labelGPA = new JLabel("GPA");
      labelCampus = new JLabel("Campus");
      labelAddress = new JLabel("Address");
      labelPhone = new JLabel("Phone Number");
      labelEmail = new JLabel("Email");
      labelCurrent = new JLabel("Current CST courses");
      labelPast = new JLabel("Past CST courses");
      labelFuture = new JLabel("Future CST courses");
      labelNotes = new JLabel("Notes");
      txtID = new JTextField(20);
      txtName = new JTextField(20);
      txtMajor = new JTextField(20);
      txtGPA = new JTextField(20);
      txtCampus = new JTextField(20);
      txtAddress = new JTextField(20);
      txtPhone = new JTextField(20);
      txtEmail = new JTextField(20);
      txtCurrent = new JTextField(20);
      txtPast = new JTextField(20);
      txtFuture = new JTextField(20);
      txtNotes = new JTextField(20);


      txtID.setDocument(new IAdvise.JTextFieldLimit(8)); 

      txtID.addKeyListener(keyListener); 

      tablePanel = new JPanel();
      tablePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      tablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 2, 0, 10));
      tablePanel.add(table.getTableHeader());
      tablePanel.add(table);
      JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(tablePanel);
      scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
      scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
      JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
      contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
      contentPane.add(scrollPane);

      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnAdd, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnEdit, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      buttonPanel.add(btnDelete, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSort, c);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 20;
      c.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      buttonPanel.add(btnSave, c);

      frame = new JFrame("Tutoring Database");
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
      frame.pack();

      addPanel = new JPanel();
      addPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

      c.insets = new Insets(1, 0, 1, 1);
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridy = 0;
      addPanel.add(labelID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      addPanel.add(labelName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      addPanel.add(labelMajor, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      addPanel.add(labelGPA, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      addPanel.add(labelCampus, c);
      c.gridy = 5;
      addPanel.add(labelAddress, c);
      c.gridy = 6;
      addPanel.add(labelPhone, c);
      c.gridy = 7;
      addPanel.add(labelEmail, c);
      c.gridy = 8;
      addPanel.add(labelCurrent, c);
      c.gridy = 9;
      addPanel.add(labelPast, c);
      c.gridy = 10;
      addPanel.add(labelFuture, c);
      c.gridy = 11;
      addPanel.add(labelNotes, c);
      // text fields
      c.gridx = 1;
      c.gridy = 0;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtID, c);
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtName, c);
      c.gridy = 2;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtMajor, c);
      c.gridy = 3;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtGPA, c);
      c.gridy = 4;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtCampus, c);
      c.gridy = 5;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtAddress, c);
      c.gridy = 6;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtPhone, c);
      c.gridy = 7;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtEmail, c);
      c.gridy = 8;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtCurrent, c);
      c.gridy = 9;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtPast, c);
      c.gridy = 10;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtFuture, c);
      c.gridy = 11;
      c.ipady = 1;
      addPanel.add(txtNotes, c);

      buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
      buttonPanel2.add(btnAddInput);
      buttonPanel2.add(btnCancel);

      frame1 = new JFrame("Student Database");
      frame1.setVisible(false);
      frame1.setResizable(false);
      frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame1.add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame1.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      frame1.pack();
   }// end

   KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        @Override
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      }

        @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

         if (!(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) && !(keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105)
                  && !(keyCode >= 37 && keyCode <= 40) && !(keyCode == 127 || keyCode == 8)) {
            txtID.setEditable(false);
         }
      }

        @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         txtID.setEditable(true);
      }
   };

   class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        @Override
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
         if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
               btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
               btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Add Student")) {
               txtID.setText("");
               txtName.setText("");
               txtMajor.setText("");
               txtGPA.setText("");
               txtCampus.setText("");
               txtAddress.setText("");
               txtPhone.setText("");
               txtEmail.setText("");
               txtCurrent.setText("");
               txtPast.setText("");
               txtFuture.setText("");
               txtNotes.setText("");
                Student student = new Student(txtID.getText(), txtName.getName(), txtMajor.getText(), txtGPA.getText(), txtCampus.getText(), txtAddress.getText(), txtPhone.getText(),txtEmail.getText(), txtCurrent.getText(), txtPast.getText(), txtFuture.getText(), txtNotes.getText());
                al.add(student);

               frame1.setTitle("Add Student data"); // title bar name for add
               frame1.setVisible(true);

               } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EDIT")) {
               txtID.setText(data[rowIndex][0] + ""); 
               txtName.setText(data[rowIndex][1] + ""); 
               txtMajor.setText(data[rowIndex][2] + "");
               txtGPA.setText(data[rowIndex][3] + "");
               txtCampus.setText(data[rowIndex][4] + "");
               txtAddress.setText(data[rowIndex][5] + "");
               txtPhone.setText(data[rowIndex][6] + "");
               txtEmail.setText(data[rowIndex][7] + "");
               txtCurrent.setText(data[rowIndex][8] + "");
               txtPast.setText(data[rowIndex][9] + "");
               txtFuture.setText(data[rowIndex][10] + "");
               txtNotes.setText(data[rowIndex][11] + "");
               txtID.setEditable(false); 
               frame1.setTitle("Enter Student data"); 
               btnAddInput.setActionCommand("Edit2");
               btnAddInput.setText("ACCEPT");

               frame1.setVisible(true); 
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("DELETE")) {
               int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "ARE YOU SURE?", "CONFIRM",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

               if (confirm == 0) {
                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  rowNumber = 0;

                  noOfStudents--;
                  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                     if (rowIndex != i && i <= noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = data[i][0];
                        data[rowNumber][1] = data[i][1];
                        data[rowNumber][2] = data[i][2];
                        data[rowNumber][3] = data[i][3];
                        data[rowNumber][4] = data[i][4];
                        data[rowNumber][5] = data[i][5];
                        data[rowNumber][6] = data[i][6];
                        data[rowNumber][7] = data[i][7];
                        data[rowNumber][8] = data[i][8];
                        data[rowNumber][9] = data[i][9];
                        data[rowNumber][10] = data[i][10];
                        data[rowNumber][11] = data[i][11];


                        rowNumber++;
                     } else if (rowIndex != i && i > noOfStudents) {
                        data[rowNumber][0] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][1] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][2] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][3] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][4] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][5] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][6] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][7] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][8] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][9] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][10] = "";
                        data[rowNumber][11] = "";

                        rowNumber++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (noOfStudents == 1000) {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                   }
                  else {
                       btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                   }
                  if (noOfStudents == 0) {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                  if (data[rowIndex][0] == null || data[rowIndex][0] == "") {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                  } else {
                     btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                     btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                  }

                  table.updateUI();

               }
            } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("AddInput")) {

               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtMajor.getText().isEmpty()// /
                        || txtGPA.getText().isEmpty() || txtCampus.getText().isEmpty()|| txtEmail.getText().isEmpty()
                       || txtCurrent.getText().isEmpty()|| txtPast.getText().isEmpty()|| txtFuture.getText().isEmpty()
                       || txtNotes.getText().isEmpty() || txtPhone.getText().isEmpty()) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE FILL IN THE BLANKS.", "ERROR!",
                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               }
                else {
                  int dup = 0;
                  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                     if (txtID.getText().equals(data[i][0])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS.", "ERROR!",
                                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        dup++;
                     }
                  }
                  if (dup == 0) {
                     rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
                     data[noOfStudents][0] = txtID.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][1] = txtName.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][2] = txtMajor.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][3] = txtGPA.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][4] = txtCampus.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][5] = txtAddress.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][6] = txtPhone.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][7] = txtEmail.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][8] = txtCurrent.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][9] = txtPast.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][10] = txtFuture.getText();
                     data[noOfStudents][11] = txtNotes.getText();



                     table.updateUI();
                     frame1.dispose();
                     noOfStudents++;
                     if (noOfStudents == 50){
                        btnAdd.setEnabled(false);
                     }
                        else {
                          btnAdd.setEnabled(true);
                      }
                     if (data[rowIndex][0] == null) {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(false);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
                     } else {
                        btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
                        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
                     }
                  }
               }
               table.updateUI();
            }else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Save")){
                try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Tutor.txt");
            for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
          out.print(data[i][j]);
          out.print(", ");
      if(j == 10){   
         out.println();
      }
      }     out.flush();

        }} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
              } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Update")) {

            }
               if (txtID.getText().isEmpty() || txtName.getText().isEmpty()
                        || txtMajor.getText().isEmpty()// /
                        || txtGPA.getText().isEmpty() || txtCampus.getText().isEmpty()|| txtEmail.getText().isEmpty()
                       || txtCurrent.getText().isEmpty()|| txtPast.getText().isEmpty()|| txtFuture.getText().isEmpty()
                       || txtNotes.getText().isEmpty()) {
               } else {
                  data[rowIndex][0] = txtID.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][1] = txtName.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][2] = txtMajor.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][3] = txtGPA.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][4] = txtCampus.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][5] = txtAddress.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][6] = txtPhone.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][7] = txtEmail.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][8] = txtEmail.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][9] = txtEmail.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][10] = txtEmail.getText();
                  data[rowIndex][11] = txtEmail.getText();


                frame1.dispose();
               }
               table.updateUI();

      }
   }

   class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {
      private int limit;

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

      JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
         super();
         this.limit = limit;
      }

        @Override
      public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
               throws BadLocationException {
         if (str == null) {
                       return;
                   }

         if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
            super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
         }
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new IAdvise();
   }
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student implements java.io.Serialize{
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final String major;
    private final String gpa;
    private final String campus;
    private final String address;
    private final String number;
    private final String email;
    private final String current;
    private final String past;
    private final String future;


   public Student(String id, String name, String major,String gpa, String campus, String address,String number, String email, String current, String past, String future, String notes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.major = major;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.campus = campus;
        this.address = address;
        this.number = number;
        this.email = email;
        this.current = current;
        this.past = past;
        this.future = future;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) next time. It will show, that you are understanding, what you are asking for, and increase chance of good answer. Also it will save a lot of time to answerer.

Comment: Your line numbers are off.  Line 300 is some random line in the middle of `actionPerformed`.  I'm not clear on what you're asking... are you asking how to create an `ArrayList` from an existing array, or are you asking how to modify code that currently uses an array so that it uses an `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: Im asking how to modify the code to use an ArrayList. Sorry about the unclarity

Comment: Try using the this option -    ArrayList<Element> arrayList = new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array));

Answer (score 1):

To change code that uses an array into code that uses an `ArrayList`:

1. Instead of `a[i]`, when it's not on the left side of an assignment, use `a.get(i)`
2. Instead of `a.length`, use `a.size()`
3. Instead of setting `a[i] = expression`: if `i` is known to be in range (0 <= `i` <= `a.length-1`), use `a.set(i, expression)`.  If `i == a.length`, you couldn't use `a[i] = expression` with an array, but you can do it with an `ArrayList`, increasing the size by 1: `a.add(expression)`.  If `i > a.length`, so that you want to add a new element in the `ArrayList` leaving a gap, then something like:

   ```
   while (a.size() < i)
       a.add (null);
   // at this point a.size == i
   a.add (expression);
   // now a.size == i+1
   ```

That should cover all the basic operations on arrays.  There are some utility operations defined in `Arrays` that don't have equivalent operations in `ArrayList`, like `binarySearch`.