# Converting a program with int[] arrays to array lists

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if array list had respective methods that function the same as `int[]` arrays. So would something like `myArray[index]` be the same as `myArray.get(index)`(assuming that `myArray` is an array list in the second one)?

Some more examples:

`myArray.length` = `myArray.size()`

If so, I need to convert code from `int[]` arrays to array list. (By the way, `myArray` is a private `int[]`)

```
public boolean deleteZeros()
{
    int rightZero = -1;     
    for(int position1 = 0; position1 < myArray.length; position1++)
    {
        if(myArray [position1] == 0)
        {
            rightZero = position1;
        }
    }

    if(rightZero == -1)
        return false;

    int [] temp  = new int [myArray.length - rightZero -1];

    for(int position2 = 0;  position2 < temp.length; position2++ )
    {
        temp [position2] = myArray [rightZero + 1 + position2];
    }

    numMoves += 1;

    myArray = temp;

    return true;
}
```

So would that code look like this? (after replacing `myArray` with `myArrayList` and fixing the respective methods)

```
public boolean deleteZeros()
{
    int rightZero = -1;     
    for(int position1 = 0; position1 < myArrayList.size(); position1++)
    {
        if(myArrayList.get(position1) == 0)
        {
            rightZero = position1;
        }
    }

    if(rightZero == -1)
        return false;

    int [] temp  = new int [myArrayList.size() - rightZero -1];

    for(int position2 = 0;  position2 < temp.length; position2++ )
    {
        temp[position2] = myArrayList.get(rightZero + 1 + position2);
    }

    numMoves += 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i ++)
    {
        myArrayList.set(i, temp[i]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t

Comment: @codeNinja isn't that a recursive link?  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623209/how-would-i-switch-from-an-array-to-an-arraylist/20623906#20623906 (always good to be able to plug my own answers!)

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 3):

> So would something like myArray[index] be the same as myArray.get(index)(assuming that myArray is an array list in the second one)?

Yes

> Some more examples:
>
> myArray.length = myArray.size()

Yes

> So would that code look like this? (after replacing myArray with myArrayList and fixing the respective methods)

Yes it all looks good to me. Although, you could just try it.

---

However, a problem that could occur is that your `temp` array is not the same size as your original `myArrayList`, so then when setting all of your ArrayList elements to be your temp elements, some the last few elements in your ArrayList will remain unchanged. If you need clarification for what I mean, or you want me to come up with a solution for that possible case, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an `int[]` to an ArrayList, use

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList());
```

You will need to import `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: I want to change the first code from `int[]` arrays to array lists, by using the name `myArrayList`

Comment: In that case, your code is absolutely correct! ArrayLists are indexed using `get()` and the size is found using `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct a new `ArrayList`, and then `add` each integer in your `myArray` to the `ArrayList` one by one. Sample code is here:

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
List<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(myArray.length);
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArrayList.add(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists also have a method `myArray.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)` which would make it easier for you to cut your list, not neading for loops at the end.